# How to add post meta tag inside do_shortcode in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using [Coupon Creator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/coupon-creator/) and I like that it comes with the categories and shortcodes. I am using a category shortcode like this example `[coupon couponid="loop" category="Brumby's Bakery"  couponorderby="date"  coupon_align="cctor_alignnone" name="Coupon Loop"]`.

I wanted to use different category shortcode for each page. Therefore, I kinda created a custom meta box for that ([Wordpress Meta Boxes](http://themefoundation.com/wordpress-meta-boxes-guide/)) and called it in the php template page with `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'couponshortcode', true); ?>`. However, the shortcode won't work in php template page unless I use `<?php echo do_shortcode('[coupon...]'); ?>`

In the end this code which was supposed to be like that wouldn't work because of php in php.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'couponshortcode', true); ?>); ?>
```

How do I rework this php code? The only thing I could think of is to use something like var but I don't know how to make it work in php template page.

```
var $store = <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'couponshortcode', true); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode($store); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to `echo` `get_post_meta()`. This should work:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'couponshortcode', true)); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It works. I'm still learning about php for about 2-3 years and I'm still a beginner/intermediate....